Understanding Perimeter of Infected Area in Chessboard Virus Puzzle
In the Chess Board Virus Simulation found here: https://ves.ac.in/wp-content/uploads/sites/11/2015/12/Mangala_Gurjar_-_Use_of_invariants.pdf, I'm trying to understand the following statement:
"With 5 infected squares the perimeter of the infected region is at the most 20"
Currently I've got a mental block about why it must be so. I can see why it would be true if the rule for the spread were "every vertical or horizontal neighbour of an infected square will be infected."
I'm trying to think how 5 squares could be placed so that the perimeter of the infected region is 20. I know the statement is "at most," but I'm wondering if technically this could be less if we actually place the infected cells in an 8x8 grid.
Any insight much appreciated. Here's a picture of the puzzle: 
and here's a link to an online interactive version:   https://compucademy.net/chessboard-virus/virus.html

Not sure if I understand the question. The perimeter of the area in the picture is 20, is it not? And of course it will be smaller if the initial infected squares contain some orthogonally connected squares.

I think I'm adding "after the next step" to "With 5 infected squares the perimeter of the infected region is at the most 20" with no justification at all, other than that's how I first interpreted it and then I got stuck down that line  of inquiry.

The perimeter of any infected region cannot increase, this has nothing to do with the  current number of infected cells. Think about how adding a single cell that is "due" in the next step affects the perimeter.

I am assuming IP wants to know what other configurations will give Perimeter 20 & what configurations will give lesser Perimeter.

Red infected Area has maximum Perimeter 20 which OP already knows.
Blue infected Area has Perimeter 20 which is alternate maximum configuration.
Green infected Area has Perimeter 12 which is generic configuration.
Yellow infected Area has Perimeter 12 which is generic configuration.
Purple infected Area has Perimeter 10 which is minimum configuration.
